# API for data structure with indices, size_t vs int?

Tags: c, api-design

For a data structure with indices (e.g. an array list, a dynamic array, etc...), should the indices be of type `size_t` or `int`? Is there a clear reason to use one over the other?

```
fooGetByIndex(struct foo* foo, size_t index);
```

or

```
fooGetByIndex(struct foo* foo, int index);
```

Until I had it suggested to me to use `size_t` I'd always defaulted to `int` without thinking much of it. Having experimented with both I'm not quite sure which makes for a better API.

There exist many discussions on `size_t` vs `int` on a more general level, and that's not what I'm asking. I'm interested in the more specific case of designing an API for a data structure that uses indices (i.e. is array-like) but abstracts away direct array access through an API.

Semantically `size_t` is appropriate for indices of C arrays, which is the primary argument for it in this case. However if the C array is hidden behind an API (which might not even use one internally) that argument diminishes. Additionally being able to return `-1` as an error value is much easier when using `int`, whereas `(size_t)-1` is arguably more error-prone and confusing for the user of the API, despite being well-defined and even used by the C standard library in its [mbstowcs](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_mbstowcs.htm) function.

If relevant, the two APIs I'm currently working on can be found on CodeReview [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/189824/multi-purpose-generic-pointer-array-with-optional-type-checking) and [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/190428/multi-purpose-generic-dynamically-sized-array-for-data-of-any-one-type), though I'm looking for an answer that applies to API design of index-based data structures in general, not just those two examples.

Is using either `size_t` or `int` better API design in this case, or are both equally valid (i.e. the choice is subjective)?

Comment: This had been dicussed on SO's main site  under the C tag.

Comment: @alk It hasn't, not that I've been able to find anyway. Do post a link if I'm wrong. Unless you're referring to the general `size_t` vs `int` case, which isn't what's being asked here.

Comment: Is there a logical upper limit on the maximum size of your data structure?

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6004415/694576 (there probably are more)

Comment: @alk Not a bad find, but that's just the "Use `size_t` for array subscripts" argument already mentioned in the question. That argument diminishes once you're abstracting away the subscript behind an API, doesn't it? A raw C array is different from an abstract data structure that uses indices, and that difference is the point of the question.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian Not in theory, however on any platform where `int` is 32bit `INT_MAX` is going to be more than enough capacity in practice. I suppose the question only makes sense when `int` is 32bit because when it's smaller you have to use `size_t`. This hidden assumption may well hold the answer, as designing around `int` being a particular size isn't good C.

Comment: I feel the 1st basic question to answer is: Does the API need to support any negative indexes?

Comment: @alk Indices are virtually always non-negative, are they not? But no, no negative indices. (If there were negative indices, `size_t` wouldn't be an option and the question would be meaningless anyway.)

Comment: "I suppose the question only makes sense when `int` is 32bit because when it's smaller you have to use `size_t`." Then again there's enough of a correlation between `int` width and resource availability that on any platform with a 16bit `int` 32767 of something is going to be plenty. Data structures that need the extra range provided by `size_t` could arguably be considered a special case.

Answer (score 2):

I clearly would prefer size_t, as it is an unsigned integer, and indices are >= 0. You immediately know how to use this parameter.

It is no good style returning special values as -1 for error conditions.
This will require extra code for checking. If you forget those checks at some places, this can cause hard to find bugs.

You should use an alternative way for error handling, e.g.:

- Throw an exception:
- If you e.g. request an index, you could return the error condition by return value and the index by parameter position:

  ```
  bool GetMyIndex (size_t &result);
  ```

  Usage:

  ```
  size_t returned_index = 0;
  if (!GetMyIndex(returned_index))
  {
      // handle the error
  }
  ```

Comment: Yeah, the good old C exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

There are various advantages for each of the possible approaches.

Using only one type for all indices is nice, allowing you to pass a pointer to an index, or in C++ a reference to an index, around without having to worry what exactly you are indexing.

Having an unsigned index is nice if the index values cannot ever be negative.

Having a signed index is nice because it means you don't have to be paranoid with loops like for (i = count - 1; i >= 0; --i). And you can use -1 to imply an invalid index.

Not having artificial restrictions because of the index type is nice. It's rubbish to use an int index on a 64 GByte machine that could easily handle much bigger indexes.

Not wasting space is nice. It's rubbish to have a 64 bit index that can access one of two items only.